# how to create string by adding variables in a string during runtime?

Tags: string, matlab, user-interface, strcmp

In my application, i have to create a string by adding new variables(which have IL in them) during runtime. But i am unable to do so.  when i load new value the old value is overwritten. The final sis should have all variables with IL in them. As i am new to matlab i am unable to find solution. My code is as follows

```
for i=1:1:length(vars)
    index = 0;
    index=index+1;
    sys=vars{i};
    syss=cellstr(sys);
          expression='\w*_IL\w*';
     matchStr{index} = regexp(sys,expression,'match');
     sis=matchStr{index}
end
```

also,

```
vars='a'
    'b'
    'c_IL'
    'd'
    'e_IL'
```

Please help.

Comment: Think editing to this `sis{i}=matchStr{index}` might make it work for you. Also, consider pre-allocation.

Comment: Could you please elaborate?

Comment: `sis{i}` basically tells MATLAB to store RHS of that iteration `i` as a cell of a cell array  named `sis`. Isn't that the expected output?

Comment: yes, it should append all variables comng from right hand side to a string sis, I want only fields with IL get appended in sis By your way output is comng like that  

    []    []     {1x1 cell}   []    {1x1 cell}

Comment: Look into [**`strjoin`**](http://www.mathworks.in/help/matlab/ref/strjoin.html)

Comment: How to use that in this application?

Comment: `strjoin(horzcat(sis{:}))`. Look into its doc to see how would like  to join the string outputs from each iteration.